# Python csv processing

Tags: python, csv

i have an python exercise that require write a program that extract information from 5 csv file name QLD2010.csv, QLD2011.csv, QLD2012.csv, QLD2013.csv and QLD2014.csv
In each file there some data like that:

```
Girl Names,Count of Girl Names,Boy Names,Count of Boy Names
Ruby,440,Cooper,493
Mia,425,William,493
Isabella,401,Jack,452
```

And i have to merge data from 5 file to a new csv file with this format:

```
Year,Babyname,Count of names,Gender
```

eg.

```
2010,Harper,54,Girl
2010,Hunter,195,Boy
```

I have no idea how to make the 'year' from file name and how to merge girl name and boy name in one row and show the gender. Anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Since stackoverflow is a question-and-answer-platform, but not a code writing service please add the code you got so far. There is no problem with providing some help on solving problems, however, no one would do your homework. Please take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filenames all have the same format, you can use slicing to get the years easily;

```
In [1]: filenames = 'QLD2010.csv QLD2011.csv QLD2012.csv QLD2013.csv QLD2014.csv'.split()

In [2]: filenames
Out[2]: ['QLD2010.csv', 'QLD2011.csv', 'QLD2012.csv', 'QLD2013.csv', 'QLD2014.csv']

In [4]: [fn[3:7] for fn in filenames]
Out[4]: ['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
```

Or you might want to put them into a dictionary for easy access later;

```
In [5]: {fn: int(fn[3:7]) for fn in filenames}
Out[5]: 
{'QLD2010.csv': 2010,
 'QLD2011.csv': 2011,
 'QLD2012.csv': 2012,
 'QLD2013.csv': 2013,
 'QLD2014.csv': 2014}
```

If the filenames are not so uniform, you could use regular expressions. The expression `(\d{4})` basically means: match *exactly* four digits, and return the match as a group.

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: {fn: int(re.search('(\d{4})', fn).group()) for fn in filenames}
Out[7]: 
{'QLD2010.csv': 2010,
 'QLD2011.csv': 2011,
 'QLD2012.csv': 2012,
 'QLD2013.csv': 2013,
 'QLD2014.csv': 2014}
```

With regard to processing the lines from the CSV file, it is not that difficult to split them up, assuming each line has the same form;

```
In [8]: 'Ruby,440,Cooper,493'.split(',')
Out[8]: ['Ruby', '440', 'Cooper', '493']
```

The easiest way to store the data is in a dictionary;

```
In [18]: boys, girls = {}, {}

In [19]: girls[row[0]] = int(row[1])

In [20]: boys[row[2]] = int(row[3])

In [21]: boys
Out[21]: {'Cooper': 493}

In [22]: girls
Out[22]: {'Ruby': 440}
```